# Why won't list items follow the inline CSS rule?

Tags: css, html-lists

I'm having an issue with my list. I've placed a `white-space: nowrap;` and a `display: inline;` where they belong, but for some reason there is still a line break after the `notes` list item. The output looks like this:

```
4 Months Ago    904 Notes
Laughing Squid    laughingsquid
```

When it should look like this:

```
4 Months Ago    904 Notes    Laughing Squid    laughingsquid
```

I cannot figure out what is causing the strange line break in the middle. Any help to clarify the issue and correct it would be awesome.

HTML:

```
<div class="meta">
<ul>
    <li class="date"><i class="icon-time"></i> <a href="http://creativeplayground.tumblr.com/post/19181776541/laughingsquid-tifa-the-cat-thinks-shes-a-dog" title="Creative Playground">4 months ago</a></li>
    <li class="notes"><i class="icon-heart"></i> <a href="http://creativeplayground.tumblr.com/post/19181776541/laughingsquid-tifa-the-cat-thinks-shes-a-dog#notes" title="Creative Playground">904 notes</li>
    <li class="source"><i class="icon-info-sign"></i> <a href="http://laughingsquid.com/tifa-the-cat-thinks-shes-a-dog/" title="Laughing Squid">Laughing Squid</a></li>
    <li class="reblog"><i class="icon-retweet"></i> <a href="http://links.laughingsquid.com/post/19181722635/tifa-the-cat-thinks-shes-a-dog" title="laughingsquid">laughingsquid</a></li>
</ul>
<hr class="spacer">
<ul class="tags">
    <li class="tags"><i class="icon-tags"></i></li>
    <li class="tag"><a href="http://creativeplayground.tumblr.com/tagged/fancy-tag" title="fancy tag">fancy tag</a></li><li class="tag"><a href="http://creativeplayground.tumblr.com/tagged/sample-tage" title="sample tage">sample tage</a></li><li class="tag"><a href="http://creativeplayground.tumblr.com/tagged/tag-1" title="tag 1">tag 1</a></li><li class="tag"><a href="http://creativeplayground.tumblr.com/tagged/tag-2" title="tag 2">tag 2</a></li><li class="tag"><a href="http://creativeplayground.tumblr.com/tagged/tag-3" title="tag 3">tag 3</a></li><li class="tag"><a href="http://creativeplayground.tumblr.com/tagged/tag-4" title="tag 4">tag 4</a></li><li class="tag"><a href="http://creativeplayground.tumblr.com/tagged/tag-5" title="tag 5">tag 5</a></li><li class="tag"><a href="http://creativeplayground.tumblr.com/tagged/tag-6" title="tag 6">tag 6</a></li><li class="tag"><a href="http://creativeplayground.tumblr.com/tagged/tag-7" title="tag 7">tag 7</a></li><li class="tag"><a href="http://creativeplayground.tumblr.com/tagged/tag-8" title="tag 8">tag 8</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.meta {
    width: 110%;
    margin: 5px -8px -8px -8px;
    padding: 5px;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.8);
    box-shadow: inset -5px 1px 5px #555;
    font-size: 10pt;
    color: #555;
}
.meta a:link, .meta a:visited { color: #555; }
.meta > ul, ul.tags { display: inline; list-style: none; margin: 0; }
.meta > ul > li, li.tag { display: inline; margin: 0 8px 0 0; white-space: nowrap; }
li.tag:before { content: "#"; }
```

Comment: Yes, I'll update the original post so I can use proper spacing.

Comment: @Justin: Did you notice that you didn't close the anchor tag in the second link entry? It could be a coincidence, but since your layout breaks after this entry in your browser it's worth a try. Also, I cannot recreate the described behavior (FF14).

Comment: @Zeta - Wow, I feel pretty dumb. That was the issue. I've been staring at this code for hours and couldn't figure out what was wrong. And there it is. Thank you.

Comment: @Justin: I know that feeling. Actually I thought you were messing up the grouping of the selectors. Then I noticed your actual question and the JSFiddle. Meh, had better days. Anyway, feel free to answer this question yourself, as I'm way too tired to squeeze a well written answer out of my comment above ^^".

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Zeta pointing this out, but the answer was simple. I was missing a closing anchor tag on the `notes` list item. The line in question should read:

```
<li class="notes"><i class="icon-heart"></i> <a href="#" title="notes">904 notes</a></li>
```